# gitlab auto devops test job failed on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, gitlab

I am using fresh laravel installation (v 9.2) and trying to use Gitlab Auto devops but test job is failed. I am not using any additional buildpack, gitlab(yaml) or docker files.
I tried to use variable *BUILDPACK_URL* with value *heroku/php*  but the following error occures:

```
+ [[ -n heroku/php ]]
+ title 'Fetching custom buildpack'
+ echo '----->' 'Fetching custom buildpack'
-----> Fetching custom buildpack
+ selected_path=/tmp/buildpacks/custom
+ rm -rf /tmp/buildpacks/custom
+ IFS='#'
+ read -r url commit
+ buildpack-install heroku/php '' custom
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Without the variable *BUILDPACK_URL* test job found nodejs and searching for npm test script, but all I want is to use phpunit in test job. Could anybody advise how can I use phpunit in test job with auto devops enabled?

Comment: What does Auto DevOps have to do with Heroku? How is the Heroku buildpack supposed to fit in?

Comment: @Chris Heroku builder is the default builder. Gitlab Auto Test still uses Herokuish.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/stages.html

Answer (score 0):

The [only documentation about this that I can find](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/stages.html#moving-from-herokuish-to-cloud-native-buildpacks) says

> `BUILDPACK_URL` must be in a format [supported by `pack`](https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/specify-buildpacks/)

which leads to [this page](https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/specify-buildpacks/) listing supported formats:

> | Type | Format |
> | --- | --- |
> | Relative | `<path>` |
> | Filesystem | `file://[<host>]/<path>` |
> | URL | `http[s]://<host>/<path>` |
> | Docker | `docker://[<host>]/<path>[:<tag>⏐@<digest>]` |
> | CNB Builder Resource | `urn:cnb:builder[:<id>[@<version>]]` |
> | CNB Registry Resource | `urn:cnb:registry[:<id>[@<version>]]` |

Note that [Heroku-style shorthands](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#officially-supported-buildpacks) like `heroku/php` are not listed.

Try using the full URL to a `.tar.gz` [release](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/tags) instead. At the moment, this is the latest version:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/archive/refs/tags/v221.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, tried [your link](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/archive/refs/tags/v221.tar.gz) as BUILDPACK_URL and got error:
`ERROR: failed to build: downloading buildpack: extracting from 'https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/archive/refs/tags/v221.tar.gz': reading buildpack: reading buildpack.toml: could not find entry path 'buildpack.toml': not exist`
 in build job. And error in test job is: 
`buildpack-install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/archive/refs/tags/v221.tar.gz '' custom`

`ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

Comment: Hrm, I wonder if it's looking for the [raw source code](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php), which does include a `buildpack.toml`. Try this: `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/archive/refs/heads/main.tar.gz`.

Comment: got the same errors at build job and test job due to double archivation - (tar inside gz):
`ERROR: failed to build: downloading buildpack: extracting from 'https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/archive/refs/heads/main.tar.gz': reading buildpack: reading buildpack.toml: could not find entry path 'buildpack.toml': not exist`

Comment: Additionally, Gitlab runner cannot extract zip archive from another [source](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/archive/refs/tags/v222.zip) `invalid tar header`